# java CastClassException

Tags: java, casting

I have a method that returns a list of an object type `IFRS` as follows

```
    List <Ifrs> em.createNamedQuery listrecup = ("Ifrs.all"). GetResultList;
```

the problem is in a for each

```
    for (Ifrs ifrs: listrecup) {
    }
```

`CastClassException` With The message "can not be cast to java.lang.Object to Ifrs"

Comment: What is `("Ifrs.all"). GetResultList;`?  Is `Ifrs.all` a static object?  I'm very confused by this.

Comment: Could you send us a stacktrace?

Comment: That's not a valid Java code.

Comment: With this code you can't even compile your class. It is ClassCastException, not CastClassException.

Comment: does this thing even compile?

Answer (score 1):

listrecup isn't the Ifrs[] type. It seems it's Object[] type - you cannot cast Object to Ifrs (if it is not Ifrs, actually). You can check if you can cast your object to another class using `instanceof` operator:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listrecup.length; i++){
    if (ifrs instanceof Ifrs) {
        // Yay! We can cast!
        Ifrs ifrs = (Ifrs)listrecup[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm? Why downvote? Because author of the topic didn't said exactly what (s)he wants to do?

Comment: The JPA Query returns a List, never an array.